# How to update tkinter texbox in Python during program runtime

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Python GUI program using tkinter to read data from an instrument based on a list of setpoints and to show the results of each reading in a tkinter scrolled textbox as the program is running, once the user clicks the "Start" button.

However, my program only shows the results at the end of all loops, rather than update the textbox after each loop. In actual usage, the program might run for many tens of minutes due to the large number of test points.

I tried using the .after method, to allow the GUI to update, but the program does not update the textbox during each loop.

How can I modify my code so that the tkinter textbox in the GUI is updated during each loop?

Here is my simplified code using random results as a sample instrument reading:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
from tkinter import ttk

def start_measurement():
    import random
    test_points = [tp for tp in range(1,5)]
    for setpoint in test_points:
        data_reading = random.normalvariate(setpoint,0.05/2)
        data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"Setpoint = {:.3f}, Reading = {:.3f}\n".format(setpoint, data_reading))
        data_results.after(1000)
    data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"\nDone\n")
    
root = tk.Tk()
    
# Create main frame for entire program: mainframe
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10", style='bgstyle.TFrame')
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.W, tk.E, tk.S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
# Create Data Output Text Box with Vertical Scrollbar
data_label = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Results")
data_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(30,30), pady=(20,0), sticky=(tk.S,tk.W,tk.E))
data_results =  tkscrolled.ScrolledText(mainframe, width=100, height=20)
data_results.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(30,30), pady=(0,20), sticky=(tk.N,tk.W,tk.E))

start_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, width=15, text="Start", command=lambda:start_measurement())
start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(30,30), pady=(20,0), sticky=(tk.N, tk.W))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: simple, don't use any loop other than `.after` "loops" or use threading (and `.after` loops)

Comment: Matiiss, I don't really understand your suggestion "don't use any loop other than .after "loops" ". Can you be more specific?

Comment: well, simply don't use `for`, `while` loops in `tkinter` (unless they are super quick or other cases where you put them in threads and stuff, but not slow loops that take while in the main thread), basically the accepted answer is kinda what I meant

Comment: @Matiiss, Got it. Thanks for the clarification. I'll try to stick with .after recursive functions wherever possible instead of other loops.

Comment: btw they are not exactly recursive functions, that would lead to `UnboundLocalError` or sth because of maximum recursion depth, they simply place an event on the `mainloop` and the function gets called from there not from itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_results.after(1000)` behaves like `time.sleep(1)`.  So the updates are not shown until tkinter `mainloop()` takes back the control after the function exits.

You should use `.after()` like below:

```py
def start_measurement(setpoint=1):
    import random
    if setpoint < 5:
        start_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED) # prevent multiple executions
        data_reading = random.normalvariate(setpoint, 0.05/2)
        data_results.insert(tk.INSERT, "Setpoint = {:.3f}, Reading = {:.3f}\n".format(setpoint, data_reading))
        # execute this function one second later with updated setpoint
        data_results.after(1000, start_measurement, setpoint+1)
    else:
        data_results.insert(tk.INSERT, "\nDone\n")
        start_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL) # enable for next execution
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! My setpoints were made up, so I'll have to tweak it a bit for the real setpoints, which are a long list, and are not whole numbers. Just curious, is the only solution using recursion the way that you did in the .after statement?

Comment: You can use thread. But it is not recommended to update tkinter widgets in a thread because tkinter is not thread-safe, so you need to find another way to tell the main thread to update those widgets.  Using `.after()` is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows.

```
def start_measurement():
import random
test_points = [tp for tp in range(1,5)]
for setpoint in test_points:
    data_reading = random.normalvariate(setpoint,0.05/2)
    data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"Setpoint = {:.3f}, Reading = {:.3f}\n".format(setpoint, data_reading))
    data_results.update()
    data_results.after(1000)
data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"\nDone\n")
```

Add `data_results.update()` to your code.This updates your textbox every second.After all iteration You get 'Done' displayed.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @PCM a line: `data_results.update()`

Comment: @WalidSiddik I know. But the answer should be `updated` with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. This does work, which is an improvement over the original code, but the .after(1000) still freezes the GUI while waiting. It does update once per loop though, so it is a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `root.after` like this -

```
data_results.after(1000,lambda:data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"\nDone\n"))
```

So, after approximately 1 second it inserts `Done`. And you should keep this out of the for loop -

```
def start_measurement():
    test_points = [tp for tp in range(1,5)]
    for setpoint in test_points:
        data_reading = random.normalvariate(setpoint,0.05/2)
        data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"Setpoint = {:.3f}, Reading = {:.3f}\n".format(setpoint, data_reading))
    data_results.after(1000,lambda:data_results.insert(tk.INSERT,"\nDone\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the 1000 ms delay is needed inside the loop to wait for the instrument to get a stable reading.